# I3D Area Chart - I Need Series Labels Next to Chart, Not In Legend

Tags: ssrs-2008

SSRS 2008.  Working with 3d Area Chart.

In Excel you can label the X, Y, and the Z Axes, but in SSRS I seem to only be able to label the x and y axes and the Z axis labels seem to be only go in the Legend.  I don't want a legend though, I need to have the text describing each color area right next to it.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since charting in SSRS 2008 is an implementation of Dundas I contacted their support department where I was told that the feature I'm looking fro does not exist in either the SSRS embedded version or the box version of their product for that chart type.  I contacted other chart vendors and found anothe rbig one that does have the feature I seek, but when I attempted to us it in the demo, the results were illegible with no way to format the labels in such a way that they did not cover each other up.  I have not yet found a product (outside of Excel) that is able to clearly display labels on the Depth axis.